# React-JS Single post visit is not working | No routes matched location "/posts/1"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I wanted to make a single blog page of a blog website to read but it's not working

I want someone help me to solve this error.

App.js

```
import Demo from "./components/Pages/Demo/Demo";
import DemoPost from "./components/Pages/Demo/Post";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/posts' exact element={<Demo />} />
        <Route path='/demo/:pid' element={<DemoPost />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Posts.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Demo() {
   const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
         .then(response => response.json())
         .then(json => setPosts(json))
   }, []);

   return (
      <div className="posts">
         <div className="grid">

            {posts.map(post => (
               <div key={post.id}>
                  <Link to={`/posts/${post.id}`}>
                     <h2>{post.title}</h2>
                     <p>{post.body}</p>
                  </Link>
               </div>
            ))}
         </div>
      </div>
   )
}
export default Demo
```

Post.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function Post({ match }) {
   const [post, setPost] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
      fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts${match.params.pid}`)
         .then(response => response.json())
         .then(json => setPost(json))

      console.log(match, 'why not show match');

   }, []);

   return (
      <div className="posts">
         <div className="post-container">
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            <p>{post.body}</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   )
}

export default Post
```

Comment: Can you share your routes file?

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve] that includes the router and routes, and the component with the link you are using? It looks like you are using `react-router-dom@6` but expecting a routed component to be passed some route props like v5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the link `` <Link to={`/posts/${post.id}`}> `` you need to render a route path that matches, e.g. `path="/posts/:pid"`.

```jsx
<Routes>
  <Route path='/posts' exact element={<Demo />} />
  <Route path='/posts/:pid' element={<DemoPost />} />
</Routes>
```

`react-router-dom@6` `Route` components also no longer pass route props to the routed component. The `element` component should use the `useParams` hook to access the route path params.

```jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function Post() {
  const { pid } = useParams();

  const [post, setPost] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${pid}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setPost(json));
  }, [pid]); // <-- pid is effect dependency

  if (!post) {
    return null; // <-- or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return (
    <div className="posts">
      <div className="post-container">
        <h1>{post.title}</h1>
        <p>{post.body}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```